# Pages take long time to load after adding django-debug-toolbar

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

After adding `django-debug-toolbar` , my pages (all of them) load after a lot of time, more than 5 mins. And if it does not load, it gives `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

I am using Django 1.7, django-debug-toolbar 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `django-pipeline` & it took a huge time to load on local. If I do  `PIPELINE_ENABLED = True,` everything works fine.